# how to put div dropdown value into textbox when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

So I am having a little trouble getting my input box to function properly.
I have an Ajax live-search textbox that drops down the suggestions below the textbox as the user starts typing a value (grabbing those values from the database)... I have that part working.

What I want is for the user to be able to click one of these items in the dropdown and then the value of that item will be displayed (put) into the textbox. (Do I need to make them links or just keep them as a div?)

```
//Textbox that the user will type a value in
<input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">

//This is the div that will dropdown below the textbox
 <div class="div-table" role="scroll">
         <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id1">City1</div>
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id2">City2</div>
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id3">City3</div>
         </div>
</div>
```

I made the dropdown a certain height. I added a scroll function using role="scroll".
I also have another function on this textbox that keeps a default value in the textbox if it is left empty. It is below:

```
//This piece of jquery puts the default CURRENT SearchTerm value inside the dropdown and removes it if input onfocused.
    $('input.searchTerm').on('focus', function () {
        // On first focus, check to see if we have the default text saved
        // If not, save current value to data()
        if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).val());

        // check to see if the input currently equals the default before clearing it
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input.searchTerm').on('blur', function () {
        // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
    });
```

I tried this code below but it does not work for me.
Any suggestions or links to a fiddle solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('.div-table-col').click(function () {
       var value = $(this).text();
       var input = $('input[name=searchTerm]')
       input.val(value);
 });
```

Also as an added bonus, how can I display a message in the dropdown if there are no results found. Thanks in advance!  :)

EDIT: Here is the code for the data that I am displaying via Ajax. I am not sure if something in here may be causing the error and not putting the value into the textbox like it should.

```
   var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
   var divhtml = '<div class="div-table" id="list-group" role="scroll">';
   divhtml += '<div class="div-table-row"><div class="div-table-col city-link current-location-style" style="height:45px;padding:10px;" id="0">Current Location</div><div class="list-group-item list-city-style">City Name</div>';
   obj.forEach(function (city) {
   divhtml += '<div class="div-table-col"><a href="#" class="list-group-item city-link" id="' + city.City_ID + '">' + city.Name + ', ' + city.StateName + ', ' + city.CountryName + '</a></div>';
                        });
   divhtml += "</div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the click function does work, you just forgot a semicolon `;` in the third row.

Working example:

```js
//This piece of jquery puts the default CURRENT SearchTerm value inside the dropdown and removes it if input onfocused.
    $('input.searchTerm').on('focus', function () {
        // On first focus, check to see if we have the default text saved
        // If not, save current value to data()
        if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).val());

        // check to see if the input currently equals the default before clearing it
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input.searchTerm').on('blur', function () {
        // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
    });
    
    
    $('.div-table-col').click(function () {
       var value = $(this).text();
       var input = $('input[name=searchTerm]');
       input.val(value);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Textbox that the user will type a value in
<input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">

// This is the div that will dropdown below the textbox
 <div class="div-table" role="scroll">
         <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id1">Customer.name1</div>
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id2">Customer.name2</div>
            <div class="div-table-col" id="id3">Customer.name3</div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Itay Ganor, Your code works like it should but it still will not work on my end.

Comment: Try different browsers, double check you have a link to jQuery, don't forget to wrap your jQuery code with `$(document).ready(function() { //everything })`

Comment: Thanks Itay, Got it working, just needed to put the onclick event inside the <div> tag and wrapped the jquery in a function. works great now. :)